# Calling AWS Location API from Sagemaker: Access Denied Exception Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have been trying to run the following code in AWS Sagemaker

```
location = boto3.client('location', region_name='us-east-1')
Response = location.search_place_index_for_text(IndexName = 'explore.place', Text = 'Boston, MA')
print(Response)
```

but I get the following error

> AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when
> calling the SearchPlaceIndexForText operation: User:
> arn:aws:sts::713361781863:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20220208T112132/SageMaker
> is not authorized to perform: geo:SearchPlaceIndexForText on resource:
> arn:aws:geo:us-east-1:713361781863:place-index/explore.place

If I run the same code from my local python I get the correct response. I imagine is a permission issue connecting Sagemaker to the AWS Location Service - how do I grant access to sagemaker/update my IAM?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to `AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20220208T112132` role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "geo:SearchPlaceIndexForText",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:geo:us-east-1:713361781863:place-index/explore.place"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It worked! could have I used already one of the standard policies? Why did I have to create an inline one?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio To follow least privileged rule - you give permissions only which are needed, nothing more then absolutely necessary.  The AWS provided policies will include other permissions.